# product request from customer with quantity

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have two tables customer request and stock table

**stock_available**

```
itemid  itemname  stock
P01     phone     200
```

**customer_request**

```
orderno Cid   Cname   itemid   qty     dt
01      C01   vasu     p01     100     28-dec-2016      
02      C02   mahh     p01      80     28-dec-2016
03      c03   gggg     p01      50     29-dec-2016
```

I need to write a query with `cid,itemid,stock,qty,dt,orderno`. 
sum of qty of itemid doesnot exceeds stock and order by dt first in first out

Required result:

```
cid     itemid  stock   qty   pending    dt           orderno 
c01     p01     200     100     0        28/dec/2016  01
c02     p02     100      80     0        28/dec/2016  02
c03     p03      20      50    30        29/dec/2016  03
```

Comment: how come 3 rows appear? 100+80+50>200 ..

Comment: Customer_request table have 3 request total 230. In our stock table we have 200 nly we have to give priority to FIFO Exceeded 30 will be issued later.

Comment: but what will be the putput to your query?

Comment: i have mentioned below o/p model.i need to write a query with cid,itemid,stock,qty,dt,orderno . sum of qty of itemid doesnot exceeds stock and order by dt first in first out

requires o/p is

cid - itemid - stock - qty - pending - dt - orderno

c01 - p01 - 200 - 100 - 0 - 28/dec/2016 - 01

c02 - p02 - 100 - 80 - 0 - 28/dec/2016 - 02

c03 - p03 - 20 - 50 - 30 - 29/dec/2016 - 03

Comment: @NirmalR are you using oracle or MySQL?

Comment: oracle sql developer

Comment: that's just a tool. which DB?

Comment: i am using oracle

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT orderno, cid, cname, itemid, qty, dt,
  CASE WHEN s > 0 THEN s ELSE 0 END - LAG(CASE WHEN s > 0 THEN s ELSE 0 END,1,0) over (partition by itemid order by orderno) pending
FROM
  (SELECT c.*,
    SUM(c.qty) over (partition BY c.itemid order by c.dt, c.orderno) - s.stock s
  FROM stock_available s
  INNER JOIN customer_request c
  ON s.itemid = c.itemid
  );
```

**Test 1:**

```
select * from stock_available;

+--------+----------+-------+
| ITEMID | ITEMNAME | STOCK |
+--------+----------+-------+
| P01    | phone    | 200   |
+--------+----------+-------+

select * from customer_request;

+---------+-----+-------+--------+-----+-----------+
| ORDERNO | CID | CNAME | ITEMID | QTY | DT        |
+---------+-----+-------+--------+-----+-----------+
| 1       | C01 | vasu  | P01    | 100 | 28-DEC-16 |
+---------+-----+-------+--------+-----+-----------+
| 2       | C02 | mahh  | P01    | 80  | 28-DEC-16 |
+---------+-----+-------+--------+-----+-----------+
| 3       | C03 | gggg  | P01    | 50  | 29-DEC-16 |
+---------+-----+-------+--------+-----+-----------+
```

Result of my query:

```
+---------+-----+-------+--------+-----+-----------+---------+
| ORDERNO | CID | CNAME | ITEMID | QTY | DT        | PENDING |
+---------+-----+-------+--------+-----+-----------+---------+
| 1       | C01 | vasu  | P01    | 100 | 28-DEC-16 | 0       |
+---------+-----+-------+--------+-----+-----------+---------+
| 2       | C02 | mahh  | P01    | 80  | 28-DEC-16 | 0       |
+---------+-----+-------+--------+-----+-----------+---------+
| 3       | C03 | gggg  | P01    | 50  | 29-DEC-16 | 30      |
+---------+-----+-------+--------+-----+-----------+---------+
```

**Test 2:**

```
-- Added one more request
insert into customer_request values(4, 'C04','some','P01',400,'30-Dec-2016');

+---------+-----+-------+--------+-----+-----------+---------+
| ORDERNO | CID | CNAME | ITEMID | QTY | DT        | PENDING |
+---------+-----+-------+--------+-----+-----------+---------+
| 1       | C01 | vasu  | P01    | 100 | 28-DEC-16 | 0       |
+---------+-----+-------+--------+-----+-----------+---------+
| 2       | C02 | mahh  | P01    | 80  | 28-DEC-16 | 0       |
+---------+-----+-------+--------+-----+-----------+---------+
| 3       | C03 | gggg  | P01    | 50  | 29-DEC-16 | 30      |
+---------+-----+-------+--------+-----+-----------+---------+
| 4       | C04 | some  | P01    | 400 | 30-DEC-16 | 400     |
+---------+-----+-------+--------+-----+-----------+---------+
```

**Test 3:**

```
insert into stock_available values ('P02','something else',10);
insert into customer_request values(5, 'C05','someone','P02',50,'30-Dec-2016');

+---------+-----+---------+--------+-----+-----------+---------+
| ORDERNO | CID | CNAME   | ITEMID | QTY | DT        | PENDING |
+---------+-----+---------+--------+-----+-----------+---------+
| 1       | C01 | vasu    | P01    | 100 | 28-DEC-16 | 0       |
+---------+-----+---------+--------+-----+-----------+---------+
| 2       | C02 | mahh    | P01    | 80  | 28-DEC-16 | 0       |
+---------+-----+---------+--------+-----+-----------+---------+
| 3       | C03 | gggg    | P01    | 50  | 29-DEC-16 | 30      |
+---------+-----+---------+--------+-----+-----------+---------+
| 4       | C04 | some    | P01    | 400 | 30-DEC-16 | 400     |
+---------+-----+---------+--------+-----+-----------+---------+
| 5       | C05 | someone | P02    | 50  | 30-DEC-16 | 40      |
+---------+-----+---------+--------+-----+-----------+---------+
```

Comment: Hi. it does'nt return any value but query executed ORDERNO    CID        CNAME      ITEMID     QTY                    DT                        PENDING                
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------------------- ------------------------- ---------------------- 

0 rows selected

Comment: Thank u sir its working

Comment: What if I add another item, say P2 with a stock of 10 and a new order for this item, with a qty of 50?

Comment: sir is it possible to display stock from stock_available

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from 
stock_available s , 
customer_request cr 
where s.itemid = cr.itemid
order by cr.dt asc, cr.qty desc;
```

Comment: @NirmalR.: check the answer

Comment: Dear sir this will show the results nly i need my sum(qty) for itemid doesnot exceeds stock. and sort by dt and orderno First come first serve

Comment: I dont understand your question..nly(what is this?)???

Comment: i have table stock

Comment: in that stock table i stored items i have with me for example biscuits 20

Comment: after that a person raise a request e need 10 biscuits another person ask 15 total 25 request but i have only 20 in my stock. i have to issue the product to customer who raise me request first for second person i have to kept pending requst